# How to recognize QR code from image using ZXing library?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, qr-code, zxing

I have Xamarin Android project and I would like to recognize QR code from camera and save picture to storage at the same time. I used Android.Hardware.Camera.IPreviewCallback to get image from camera. Saving image works as expected but recognition of QR code fails. Here is my code:

```cs
void Android.Hardware.Camera.IPreviewCallback.OnPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
{
    byte[] jpegData = ConvertYuvToJpeg(data);
    Bitmap bitmap = BytesToBitmap(jpegData);
    SaveBitmapImage(bitmap); // This works great


    var width = (int)_textureView.Width;
    var height = (int)_textureView.Height;

    // How to get LuminanceSource??
    //LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(rgbValues, bm.Width, bm.Height, RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.ARGB32);
    //LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource( jpegData, width, height);
    LuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, 
        0, 0, width, height, false);
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
    var result = reader.decode(binaryBitmap);
}
```

Call to

```cs
var result = reader.decode(binaryBitmap);
```

always returns null.

Edit:

It seems that problem is with camera. It is not focusing on QR code, image is blurry and ZXing library is unable to decode it. How can I make camera focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with camera focus. Focus mode must be set. Here is a code:

```cs
var parameters = _camera.GetParameters();
parameters.FocusMode = GetOptimalFocusMode(parameters);
_camera.SetParameters(parameters);

private String GetOptimalFocusMode(Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters)
{
    String result;
    IList<String> focusModes = parameters.SupportedFocusModes;

    if (focusModes.Contains(Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousVideo))
    {
        result = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousVideo;
    }
    else if (focusModes.Contains(Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeAuto))
    {
        result = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeAuto;
    }
    else
    {
        result = parameters.SupportedFocusModes.First();
    }

    return result;
}
```